# (Windows Store App - Xaml/C#) animating custom dependency property always requires EnableDependentAnimation

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-store-apps, dependency-properties

**The set up:**
In a Windows Store Application using Xaml/C# I'm using a UserControl with a DependencyProperty called FadeLevel.  The property has an OnPropertyChanged handler that updates the Opacity of a UIElement in the UserControl.

**The problem:**
When I try to animate this property I have to set EnableDependentAnimation to True in order to get the animation to work. At which point is does work and works well.

**Why I'm confused:**
Opacity is not a property that requires enabling Dependent animations, only properties that effect layout require this.

**My Rationale:**
I suppose that the run time does not know what this property is doing and assumes it to be dependent.

**Please enlighten me:**
Is that really how it works?  If you have you're own custom dependency property you will always have to enable dependent animations in order to animate it regardless of underlying udpate being dependent or not?

Please help me understand why the runtime works this way or if I've missed something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the criteria listed in the [Dependent and independent animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx#dependent) in the [Storyboarded animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx) docs on MSDN:

> An animation is independent if it has any of these characteristics:
>
> - The Duration of the animation is 0 seconds
> - The animation targets UIElement.Opacity
> - The animation targets a sub-property value of these UIElement    properties: RenderTransform, Projection, Clip
> - The animation targets Canvas.Left or Canvas.Top
> - The animation targets a Brush value and uses a SolidColorBrush,    animating its  Color
> - The animation is an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames

The runtime doesn't know what your FadeLevel property does so it cannot treat animations targeting FadeLevel as automatically independent. Animations targeting custom properties will be independent only if they are Duration 0 or ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

Comment: I guess what really matters in the end is if there is any performance impact, which I'm guessing there is not because the underlying animation is targeting Opacity.  What is your take?  Thanks.